# Recording video worked then logcat freaked out

Tags: android, logcat

I had my android app working by recording a simple video and having it be able to play back and it just crashed and my log cat gives me a ton of errors now and i have no clue why

this is my logcat

```
12-04 23:13:38.487: D/skia(25641): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641): Failure retrieving icon 0x7f020000 in package com.example.vmbapp2
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.putCachedIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:757)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:593)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:140)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:161)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:145)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:613)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:206)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2785)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2845)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:258)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2096)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at com.example.vmbapp2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4728)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
12-04 23:13:38.487: W/PackageManager(25641):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 23:13:38.657: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(25641): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
12-04 23:13:38.677: E/(25641): Can't open file for reading
12-04 23:13:38.677: E/(25641): Can't open file for reading
12-04 23:13:52.460: D/skia(25721): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721): Failure retrieving icon 0x7f020000 in package com.example.vmbapp2
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.putCachedIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:757)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:593)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:140)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:161)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:145)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:613)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:206)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2785)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2845)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:258)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2096)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at com.example.vmbapp2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4728)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
12-04 23:13:52.470: W/PackageManager(25721):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 23:13:52.591: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(25721): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
12-04 23:13:52.601: E/(25721): Can't open file for reading
12-04 23:13:52.601: E/(25721): Can't open file for reading
12-04 23:13:55.884: W/dalvikvm(25721): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40db81f8)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.vmbapp2/com.example.vmbapp2.ActivityPlay}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1536)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1390)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3453)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at com.example.vmbapp2.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3528)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14217)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
12-04 23:13:55.894: E/AndroidRuntime(25721):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you declared ActivityPlay.java in you manifest.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error loading an image.

It could be in your layout file. 
note than the error starts when you call

```
setContentView( )
```

at

```
com.example.vmbapp2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
```

or it could be in the manifest resources.

The missing resource is icon 0x7f020000 as you see in

```
Failure retrieving icon 0x7f020000 in package com.example.vmbapp2
```

if you go to **gen/ com.example.vmbapp2/R.java** and look for 0x7f020000, you will have information about the image name that is causing the error.

Comment: okay yea I am trying to make three different button on my app to store and record video on to the phone I just tried some of the things you said but no luck yet been stuck on it for two days. I want to make a button on the home screen called record that records a video thats it

Comment: this is all i have for layout

Comment: either in layout, or in the manifest, you are referencing an image or drawable that cannot be loaded properly. 
In your R.java you should have something like   **public static final int YOURFILENAME=0x7f020000;** with that you can find out where the error is, looking in your layout or manifest for that name, and looking in your resources to check if the image exists and you can open it. 
Did you look in your R.java?

Answer (score 0):

this is what my manifest looks like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vmbapp3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.vmbapp3.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my R.java

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class dimen {
        /**  Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. 

         Customize dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml (such as
         screen margins) for sw720dp devices (e.g. 10" tablets) in landscape here.

         */
        public static final int activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f040000;
        public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f040001;
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f080004;
        public static final int choose=0x7f080002;
        public static final int play=0x7f080001;
        public static final int record=0x7f080003;
        public static final int textView1=0x7f080000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class menu {
        public static final int main=0x7f070000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int Choose=0x7f050003;
        public static final int Play=0x7f050002;
        public static final int Record=0x7f050004;
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f050001;
        public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;
        public static final int record=0x7f050006;
        public static final int welcome_to_vmb=0x7f050005;
    }
    public static final class style {
        /** 
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.


        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.

 API 11 theme customizations can go here. 

        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.

 API 14 theme customizations can go here. 
         */
        public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f060000;
        /**  Application theme. 
 All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. 
         */
        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f060001;
    }
}
```